# Using Rake with Rufus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rufus-scheduler

I'm trying to user rake and [rufus](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler), both of which I am new to. I want to have Rufus call my rake task but  I am getting the following error.  `Don't know how to build task 'inbox:process_inbox'`

lib/tasks/inbox_tasks.rb

```
namespace :inbox do
  task :process_inbox do
    logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.to_s + "/log/scheduler.log")
    logger.info "Rufus Here!"
  end
end
```

rufus_scheduler.rb

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
require 'rake'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '10s', :first_at => Time.now + 3 do
  Rake::Task["inbox:process_inbox"]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jmettraux  (**the creator of rufus-scheduler!**) has already answered, the problem is that the rake task is defined in a `.rb` file instead of `.rake` file.

Adding some more details to help in the future.

While creating a new rake task, you could get the rails generator to automatically create the file with appropriate structure.

Example: Running

```
> rails g task inbox process_inbox
create  lib/tasks/inbox.rake
```

will create a file named `lib/tasks/inbox.rake` with content:

```
namespace :inbox do
 desc "TODO"
 task process_inbox: :environment do
 end 

end
```

Having a `DESC` in the task definition is important; that allows for verifying that the rake task is defined and available, by running either `rake -T inbox` or `rake -T | grep inbox`

```
> rake -T inbox
rake inbox:process_inbox  # TODO
```

Comment: Thanks Prakash for the detailed answer. I hope it gets accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Could this one help?

[How to build task 'db:populate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334520/dont-know-how-to-build-task-dbpopulate) (renaming inbox_tasks.rb to inbox_tasks.rake)

(did a simple https://www.google.com/?#q=rails+don%27t+know+how+to+build+task ...)